# How does one denote that a cell value is not available / doesn't make sense in a table?

Tags: writing, tables

I have a table that compares the performance of different systems according to different error measures:

```
System   | Error 1 | change | Error 2 | ...
--------------------------------------| ...
Baseline | 0.6     | -      | ...
A        | 0.1     | -0.5   | ...
B        | 0.3     | -0.3   | ...
C        | 0.7     |  0.1   | ...
D        | 0.6     |  0.0   | ...
```

I currently chose `-` to denote that the value does not make sense. Of course, I can subtract the error of the baseline system from itself and get 0. But I don't think that makes sense.

Should I put `-` in that cell? Or `--` or `---` (I write the document with LaTeX) or eventually something different like `N/A`? Or make the cell black?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about visualizing information and table formatting, not specific to academia.

Comment: @StephanKolassa but many academic fields have very specific style guides that aren't necessarily about the best way to visualize things.

Comment: Related to: [How to display a division by zero in a grid?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/62979/how-to-display-a-division-by-zero-in-a-grid/63000#63000)

Comment: Questions about formatting of statistics are [off-topic on Academia.SE](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/questions/3522/are-questions-about-formatting-and-presenting-results-off-topic).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it is self-evident (remember to look at your table from the perspective of a reader) I would just leave the cell empty. Less clutter is better. When not, I would tend towards `--`. More importantly I would add a footnote to the table explaining what `--` means. I think the footnote is in that case more important than the difference between `-`, `--`, and `---`.

Answer (score 5):

I cannot find any mention of what to do with missing data in the [APA style](http://www.apastyle.org/), [MLA style](http://www.mla.org/style), or [Chicago style](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/home.html), but according to [this website on AMA style](http://www.docstyles.com/amastat.htm#Sec23) says:

> Missing data and blank space in the table field (ie, and empty cell) may create ambiguity and should be avoided . . . . An ellipsis
>   (. . .) may be used to indicate no data are available [or applicable]. (p87)